# how to run pod spec file

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart

I am trying to implement the firebase dynamic link plugin in Flutter

I had I achieved in native iOS and android

now is the time to implement Flutter

I created plugin using the template

```
flutter create --org com.sample --template=plugin firebasedynamiclink
```

I had added firebase core, and firebase dynamic link dependency in pod spec in the iOS section

created the firebase app in one of the projects and got googleserviceInfo.plist file added example-> runner-> directory

Now my question is how to run a pod spec file to integrate core and dynamic link pages to iOS class files

generally, I used to run pod install but here no pod file is there.

It shows output if I add #import "Firebase/Firebase.h"
in dynamiclinkplugin.m

```
  Xcode's output:
↳
=== BUILD TARGET app_referrals OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
/Users/Siva/IdeaProjects/app_referrals/ios/Classes/AppReferralsPlugin.m:2:9: fatal error: 'Firebase/Firebase.h' file not found
#import "Firebase/Firebase.h"
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

my pod spec looks like this

```
 #
 # To learn more about a Podspec see      http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html
 #
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
   s.name             = 'app_referrals'
    s.version          = '0.0.1'
   s.summary          = 'A new flutter plugin project to refer your application using native dynamic links .'
   s.description      = <<-DESC
 A new flutter plugin project.
                   DESC
   s.homepage         = 'http://example.com'
   s.license          = { :file => '../LICENSE' }
   s.author           = { 'xyzzy Technologies' => 'siva@xyz.com'      }
   s.source           = { :path => '.' }
   s.source_files = 'Classes/**/*'
  s.public_header_files = 'Classes/**/*.h'
  s.dependency 'Flutter'
  s.dependency 'Firebase/Core'
  s.dependency 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
  s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'
  end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `#import <Firebase/Firebase.h>` or `@import Firebase;`? Also, show your Podfile for better help.

Comment: #import<Firebase/Firebase.h>

Comment: Able to find pospec but not pod file.

Comment: To use any framework, including Firebase, you need to have a Podfile in your app which will be used to install dependencies of your app. Check 'Add SDK' section [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup).

Comment: i know that and i will agree with you

Comment: But here it is plugin not individual app

Comment: Did you try importing firebase as I mentioned in first comment? Can you show your Podspec?

Comment: I had tried that, it shows error as shown in above question,i will show my pod spec in my question.

Comment: @execv sorry for the delay

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171478/discussion-between-siva-kumar-and-execv).

Comment: @execv if I tried to create pod it shows as [!] No Xcode project found, please specify one